# How to protect my database value after project start again(update)?

Tags: java, postgresql, google-app-engine, create-table

I have a project on google app-engine platform. When I change some code, I upload new project this platform and delete old project. But there are lots of users and their information, files etc in PostgreSQL database. When my new project start, my database create , so all values missing. Sometimes my table column have to change. For example : in first project I was not obligatory send verify e-mail, so I do not save user's e-mail address. After that I decided send user e-mail. Add my database user's table new column (e-mail column) After that update project , (upload updating version and create database again) How can I protect old database value?

Comment: Hi, is there a reason why you need to delete the whole Project? The Cloud SQL instances are associated to the Projects themselves and therefore you will loose all the information. Why aren't you simply running ```gcloud app deploy``` after the code on your GAE app changes, instead of deleting the whole project?

Comment: Actually I can change my code on VI screen but sometimes my code change one hundred or more line and sometimes my database table changeable. I explain it before (e-mail column added on new version). Can you explain what does GAE mean and can you explain is that a way add some code and add some column on db without delete project and without add and start new project ?  I searched but fount nothing. (I found fixtures table but I am not sure is it correct way) Thank you so much :) .  @Daniel Ocando

Comment: GAE stands for Google App Engine. In Google Cloud Platform (GCP) a [project resource](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects) is different than a GAE application. As I understand your current workflow consists of a GCP project that has a [GAE application using Java as runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/) that uses a PostgreSQL database to store some user's information. Please let me know if I understood your workflow correctly. Are you using a Cloud SQL instance? GAE standard or flex?

Comment: I use PostgreSQL on platform GAE. I upload my project (create mode) and then run my project. All database value is gone. If I upload my project on update mode. I can not change my database column.(I can not add new column) And takes too long time. I try only one or two user's info. Update mode takes two hours. Maybe 2 month later my user's count will be 100. Maybe I have to add new column :( What can I do :(  I search flyway but I understand flyway working on protect-update-insert only database schema. Not database values.. Is that correct ? How Can I protect my database value(user's info etc)

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment because not enough reputation, so i just assume you are using spring boot and have application.properties as configuration.

In application.properties file you need to change or add this line :

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Using "none" so hibernate will not drop existing table. If you need to change table based on existing model just use "update".

Comment: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none  means I delete my project but database is protected.           spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update    means my database values protected and I can add new column like e-mail   . Is that true ?

Comment: hi, again :) Sometimes I forgot change spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update  to spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create and run my project on google platform. But this process takes long time (for only 2 or 3 users information) Maybe in the future I have 100 users and their info. What can I do ?

Comment: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none   =>    I tested on my localhost. I added new column using adding entity's parameter. I want to show this column on pgAdmin but nothing added.                                                                  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update   =>   Only updatable existing column value. can not add new column.   But protected existing value.                     spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create    => . added new column but all values missing :(